# Changing Gradients using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am attempting here is to have multiparty choices for the user to choose between allowing the background to change. I don't have a solid color background but instead a gradient background. The user input is radial buttons and I have the onClick set to function colorthatisbeingchanged(). Then the function would be used to change the background gradient color. I thought about assigning variables to be changed but I don't know how to use them within CSS. I also tried attempting something like this but it hasn't worked either.

```
 document.getElementById("body1").style.background = radial-gradient(red, black);
```

my CSS for the body reads:

```
 #body1
{

    height: 137%;

    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(purple, black);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(purple, black);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(purple, black);
    background: radial-gradient(purple, black); 
    }
```

For Full Site to view click [Here](https://drive.google.com/a/usd416.org/folderview?id=0B6mYJQHjx8EMUmhsQU5NTG1uejA&usp=sharing) I'm Sure I will be back asking more questions eventually.

Thanks Everyone!

-Blake

Comment: We need permission to view that file.

Comment: Please do **not** link to you site as it most likely changes or the the link will go dead making the resource completely redundant for any future user with similar issues. Please include all relevant code in the question directly and in addition create an isolated demo using [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: What might be easier is to separate different gradient styles into separate classes, i.e: `.gradient1, .gradient2`, giving them obviously more meaningful names, instead of `#body1{}` and use JavaScript to switch classes instead. That way you also will keep presentation (CSS) and logic (JavaScript) separated. It also makes the code more maintainable. No script changes if only styles for those classes has to be updated, etc..

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, strings must be delimited with quotes:

```
target.style.backgroundImage = "radial-gradient(red, black)";
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tse7/)